# Read raw text of document body with rvest?

Tags: html, rvest

I am stupidly trying to read the raw text content of a website.
The purpose is to create a corpus for text analysis (e.g. word frequencies).
So I want all html stripped away, and content inside  tags to be returned as raw text :-)

Using this code:

thispage <- read_html(nextpage)
write (thispage, file, append=TRUE, sep="")

generates an error because read_html() returns an array of pointers:

I would submit the err msg here if the interface would let me, 
but I just get a red box saying "your post appears to contain code", and then some instructions that dont work with chrome anyway.

I know I can use SelectorGadget etc. to pinpoint specific objects of the DOM and retrieve those. But I was hoping for an easier way. Does it exist?

Thanks + cheers,
Ego

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to try the standard `rvest` way of scraping: get all html, then select you id's and grabbing the raw text:

```
"http://yoururl.com" %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes("#your_tag") %>% html_text()
```

Comment: Sure, that's what I've come to realise.
I've got the framework in place for it: Pagination, grab all URLs, visit them all and scrape the relevant blocks, next page...and so on.

I am currently working on processing just the titles, and keeping the processing in a separate file. Then I can develop the scraping separately to generate the greater corpus later.